# c# return System.Byte[] ,I want to open in python

Tags: c#, python, python.net

I am try to use a .NET Assembly in a python application using Python.NET. The C# code captures an image, that i want to use with python. Let's say I have the following C# func:

```
public byte[] GetLabelImage()
    {
        byte[] labelData = this.m_MdsFile.GetLabelData();
        if (labelData != null)
        {
            return labelData;
        }
        string path = Path.Combine(this.m_NameInfo.SlideDirName, "label.jpg");
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            return null;
        }
        return File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    }
```

When I use Python.Net in python i do the following:

```
import clr
import sys

from PIL import Image
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


b = clr.AddReference("Motic.DigitalSlide")


from Motic.DigitalSlide import *
obj = DigitalSlideFile("./123.mds")
a = obj.GetLabelImage()

print(a)

y=Image.open(io.BytesIO(a))
plt.figure("Image")
plt.imshow(y)
plt.axis('off')  
plt.show()
exit()
```

but This gives me the output:

```
C:\Users\sk\Desktop\mds\bin\Motic\x86>python mds.py
System.Byte[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mds.py", line 18, in <module>
    y=Image.open(io.BytesIO(a))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Byte[]'

C:\Users\sk\Desktop\mds\bin\Motic\x86>
```

Comment: Try this `y=Image.open(bytearray(a))` or `y=Image.open(bytes(a))`

Comment: thanks！They both work